# Chaning permission of wireless device wlan0

Tags: wireless, privileges

I want to be able to change the permission of wlan0 so that I can use tcpdump to listen on it without elevating myself to root.

Currently:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0
```

gives:

```
tcpdump: wlan0: You don't have permission to capture on that device
```

when I do:

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0
```

it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A little explaination: it is not the wlan0 device that is stopping you from capturing on it as a non-root user. This is the behavior of the kernel and is for security reasons. It's the same reason why you can't do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` as a non-root user; it would wipe your hard drive. That said, there are ways that you can override the default behavior of the kernel (ah, the beauty of Linux) to get the functionality that you want.

You could do one of two things:

I would recommend editing your sudoers file to not require a password so that you can `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0` without requiring a password to be entered every time. By editing the sudoers file you ensure that you and only you are able to do this and all other users of the system are excluded.

To do this:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add the following lines to the file:

```
Cmnd_Alias TCPDUMP_WLAN0 = /usr/bin/tcpdump -i wlan0
[username] ALL= NOPASSWD: TCPDUMP_WLAN0 #Be sure to replace [username] with your username
```

This still requires you to type "sudo" every time, but you could set a bash alias for this as well so that all you do is type `tcpdump` and it executes `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0`. To do this you simply edit the ~/.bashrc file and add the line: `alias tcpdump="/usr/bin/tcpdump -i wlan0"`

Using the sudoers file is the most security-conscious way of doing things. Now, if you're really adamant about not using `sudo` what-so-ever then I will give you want you want. However, the following command will grant all users the ability to run this program with the needed capabilities, so there's no fine user control.

Keep in mind, that this is untested, however it should work. If it doesn't I have a third solution below.

```
sudo setcap cap_net_admin+ep /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

Finally, if that doesn't work you can setuid on the file itself. What this does is it runs the program as the owner of the file (in this case, root). Like the above, anybody who executes this file will become root to run it. You should really only use this as a last resort and only if you fully trust that the program is non-exploitable and can in no way be used as a lever to compromise your system.

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/tcpdump
```